# Previewing Code in Safari? [Mac Users]

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

Hi so I recently purchased a mac and I am trying to preview my code in safari and its not working my file is saved as .html and everytime I click the file it just shows me my top sites on safari can someone please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have the reputation to comment yet.

Put the file on your desktop and Get Info.  Make sure in the name that the extension is .html and you can also try to check/uncheck Hide Extension and try that as well.  Also double check to make sure you do not have any illegal characters in your file name.

Make sure you are not using Word or Pages.  Use Text Wrangler or Sublime Text (well really any text editor that allows you to save as specific file types).

I use a Mac for all of my web coding and I have never had this issue.

Edit* If you are using an editor that allows you to choose between rich text and plain text make sure you use plain text.  TextEdit is not a plain text editor either.

Answer (score 0):

Load Chrome and then use its view > developer > view source menu option.   Works well for me!